# Nanoscroller showing Cannot read property 'style' of undefined why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is my code

```
<ul id="selectProfileOptions_IC" class="dropdownToggle_cont" ></ul>
```

I listed some names under the ul element

i used nanascroller for scroll here is my code

```
$(".dropdownToggle_cont.nano").nanoScroller({stop: true});
    $(".dropdownToggle_cont").css('height',$(".dropdownToggle").height()).addClass('nano');
    $(".dropdownToggle_cont.nano").nanoScroller();
```

it showing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

i am also added my nano.css file .

Comment: do `$(".dropdownToggle")` exist?

Comment: sorry that is $(".dropdownToggle_cont ")

Comment: Does this one referer to a valid element $(".dropdownToggle").height() ?

Comment: $(".dropdownToggle").height() when i print this lint in to console it shows 0

Comment: You need to include all the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error will occur if already a scroll generated

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when, within your `.nano` element, there's no `.nano-content` element

Comment: This answer got a downvote, but in my case it was correct.